# SignalR with Redis backplane and sticky sessions

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

we use signalr for a search engine. The user starts a search and we push them the results using signalr within the next 30 seconds. We have three servers and a redis backplate. I recognized that the memory consumption is quite high and signalr stores a lot of objects in the MemoryBus.

The question is: Can this be improved with sticky sessions on the loadbalancer? In theory when a user stays on his server, signalr can send the messages directly without the use of the backplane. This should be much faster and needs less memory. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, just in theory...